# Issues using Systemd to start a python script (code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT)

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, systemd

I'm currently trying to have a program startup when the Raspberry Pi 3 I'm using boots. The program controls a drone and will need a network connection before starting. When I try to use Systemd to start this program, I get this error message;

```
droneStartup.service - The Drone Startup service.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/droneStartup.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-04-15 14:06:24 EDT; 1s ago
  Process: 1895 ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/pi/Systemd_test.py (code=exited, status=2)
 Main PID: 1895 (code=exited, status=2)

Apr 15 14:06:24 pi systemd[1]: Started The Drone Startup service..
Apr 15 14:06:24 pi bash[1895]: from: can't read /var/mail/time
Apr 15 14:06:24 pi bash[1895]: /home/pi/Systemd_test.py: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `'Looping...''
Apr 15 14:06:24 pi bash[1895]: /home/pi/Systemd_test.py: line 4: `    print('Looping...')'
Apr 15 14:06:24 pi systemd[1]: droneStartup.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Apr 15 14:06:24 pi systemd[1]: droneStartup.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 15 14:06:24 pi systemd[1]: droneStartup.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

This is the placeholder program I'm using to test the startup;

```
from time import sleep

while True :
    print('Looping...')
    sleep(1)
```

And this is the .service file I'm using;

```
[Unit]
Description=The Drone Startup service.
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/pi/Systemd_test.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I don't know why it's coming up with a syntax error, and would greatly appreciate any help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to run a `py` file with `bash` exec.

Needs to read:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/Systemd_test.py
```

**Assuming** your Python library lives at `/usr/bin/python`